# Do you know how to prove $2(1-\cos x))<x^{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $z = x+iy$ for some real numbers $x$ and $y$.

I have to prove that 
$$\Biggl|\frac{z}{|z|}-1\Biggr|<\arg(z)$$

And now the problem reduces to prove that $2(1-\cos x))<x^{2}$

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\left|\frac{z}{|z|}-1\right|=\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1+i\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|=\lvert \cos \theta-1+i\sin \theta\rvert=\sqrt{(\cos \theta-1)^2+\sin^2 \theta}=$$

$$=\sqrt{2-2\cos \theta}<\theta \iff1-\cos \theta <\frac{\theta^2}2 \quad\theta>0$$

then consider for $x>0$

$$f(x)=\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}2>0$$

indeed $f(0)=0$ and

$$g(x)=f'(x)=-\sin x+x\ge0$$

indeed $g(0)=0$ and

$$g'(x)=1-\cos x \ge 0$$

Comment: Just a TeXnical comment: use `\lvert\cos\theta-1+i\sin\theta\rvert` and you'll appreciate the difference.

Comment: @egreg I did it, sorry but I can't appreciate any relevant difference!

Comment: With `|`: $|\cos\theta|$; with `\lvert`: $\lvert\cos\theta\rvert$

Comment: @egreg The final  result seems really closer to me, but I'll follow your suggestion on that. How could I get your notes on the topic? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

$z= |z| e^{it} = |z|(\cos t + i\sin t)\\
\arg z = t$

$|\frac {z}{|z|} - 1| \le \arg z\\
|(\cos t - 1) + i\sin t| \le t$

What is this geometrically?
[image]

The red line is shorter that the black curve.  And since the line connecting two points is the shortest path between those points, we could drop it there.

I am guessing that you have:
$|(\cos t - 1) + i\sin t| = \sqrt {(\cos t - 1)^2 + \sin^2 t} = \sqrt {2+2\cos t}$

and then you squared both sides, giving the question in this post.

I would rather suggest: $\sqrt {2+2\cos t}= 2|\sin \frac 12 t|$

and $|\sin x| \le x$ if $x\ge 0$

$2|\sin \frac 12 t| \le t$